# using tus-js-client.js with node.js 401 error

Tags: node.js, vimeo, tus, tus-js-client

using node.js with tus client  to upload video file
im trying to get upload link but keep getting 401 !!
Request failed with status code 401

```
async function createVimeoUploadLink() {
      console.log("enterig createVimeoUploadLink",accessToken);
      try {
        const response = await axios.post(
          "https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos",
          {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            
          },
          body: {
            upload: {
                "approach": "tus",
                "size": "17839845"
            }
        },
      }
        );
        const uploadLink = response.data.upload.upload_link;
      console.log('uploadLink', uploadLink)
        return uploadLink;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error("Failed to create Vimeo upload link: " + error.message);
      }
    }
```